# Adobe flex in 2021

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, flashplayer-10

I have several applications of the type .swf programmed in Adobe Flex, I saw that the browsers are not going to allow more adobe flash content. Applications are used internally in a network environment, they do not go out to the web. Is there a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Read up the **PACKAGED BROWSER SOLUTION** block here: https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe Alternately, you can just install some browser that does not block Flash and never update it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative might be the "new" Flex SDK, [Royale SDK](https://royale.apache.org/). This can be used with your old Flex app, to create web apps. Although you will need to rewrite some parts, the result is 100% web.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Adobe AIR, which will still be supported after 2020.